# BASH: syntax error near unexpected token `done' with alias named 'do'

Tags: linux, bash

this question seems frequently asked but still there is no satisfying answer regarding my issue. Hence, I was hoping you could help me out.

The following error occurs opening a terminal under Ubuntu LTE 13.04:

> syntax error near unexpected token `done' 
>   bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 225:`    done'

I checked the specific 'bash_completion' - seems fine.
Furthermore, I narrowed it down to the following command in my .bashrc file.

```
alias do='rsync -r -e ssh --exclude='file.py' user@server.xxx.de:/path/to/folder /do/here'
```

Though the following works just perfectly without raising any exceptions:

```
alias up='rsync -r -e ssh --exclude='file.py' /path/to/folder user@seerver.xxx.de:/do/here'
```

I checked if it does occur because of the `--exclude` flag, but it doesn't. Seems like something is wrong with the command. Though both commands just perfectly **do their job**. Only the first raises the error. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Unrelated, but technically, your alias is defined as the concatenation of a single-quoted string, the string `file.py`, and another single-quoted string. You can't nest single quotes; if `file.py` were `file 1.py` (containing a space), your alias would not work.

Comment: @chepner, indeed -- that's why I have an answer suggesting using a function instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bash, `do` is a reserved word.  It's looking for a `do ... done` block.  Just name your alias something else.

Comment: That it is, Jeez ... Though, beforehand the same command worked (also with 'do') with scp just fine. As we say, sometimes you are not able to see the forest because of all the trees. Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 4):

`do` is a shell keyword. You can't use it as an alias name without causing bugs.

Beyond that -- consider using functions rather than aliases; they provide substantially more control. This alias might be rewritten as so:

```
do_sync() {
  rsync -r -e ssh --exclude='file.py' \
    user@server.xxx.de:/path/to/folder \
    /do/here \
    "$@"
}
```

Using functions instead of aliases lets you do conditional logic, insert arguments in a position other than the tail, and significantly simplifies quoting (which, for your alias here, almost certainly wasn't doing what you wanted it to, since you were using the same quote type both around the alias text and within the alias text with no escaping).

Answer (score 0):

As I also said in another thread, by mistake I aliased the `local` word, which also gave the same `corrupted behavior` of the bash_completion scripts...
So, just a kind reminder to **avoid aliasing forbidden words** like `local` `do` `done` etc...
Hope it helps :)
Cheers

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the link to that other thread? It may be helpful to other users who want to see why you did things the way you did.

Comment: of course! here it is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164231/how-to-fix-corrupted-bash-completion-in-command-substitution/450917#450917